# Publish a Hosted Photo with Graph API and PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, graph, upload, photo

I'm trying to make a PHP script that will post a hosted photo to a user's profile without using the PHP SDK. This is what I have right now:

```
<?php
   $app_id = "[My App ID]";
   $app_secret = "[My App Secret]";
   $post_login_url = "[current page]";

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
   if(empty($code)){ 
      $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
       .  "&scope=publish_stream";
      echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
      . "'</script>");
     }
    else {
      $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
           . "&code=" . $code;
          $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
          $params = null;
          parse_str($response, $params);
          $access_token = $params['access_token'];






         // This would probably be where my problem is
         $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
         . "access_token=" .$access_token;
$postdata = http_build_query(
         array(
          'source' => $imageurl, //this variable has been properly defined
          'message' => $image_description //this, too, has been defined
            )
          );
         $opts = array('http' =>
         array(
          'method'=> 'POST',
          'header'=>
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => $postdata
          )
         );
      }
?>
```

When this runs, a new album with the app's name is created, but the file isn't uploaded. Is there any way to make this work? If somebody knows a solution in PHP or even javascript, please share

-Cory

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic, why are you using JavaScript to redirect, and not PHP?

header('Location: ' . $dialogue_url );

Comment: ...same reason I'm not using the PHP SDK. I get an error that would probably have an easy fix, however I honestly have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Heh, that's where we all start :-) What error do you receive? Is it something about headers already being sent?

Comment: Yeah, with the session cookies and the headers... you know, the one a lot of people seem to have had

Comment: Well, basically, all that means is that some HTML has been outputted to the browser and this means the headers have already been sent and cannot be modified after the fact.

What you can do is either use output buffering to keep all the HTML aside until the request completes or don't output anything until you've completed your logic. 

The second one is the proper way of doing this, however output buffering is a band-aid cure to the problem and does it pretty well in my experience.

Comment: You could store all your output/HTML in a variable and then at the end of your script echo it. You would be better off keeping the output in a public class variable instead of a global variable that has a chance of being unintentionally modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if you are doing a form submission you can do like this.

```
$sourceFile = $_FILES[$fileElementName];

$postdata = http_build_query(array('source' => '@'.$sourceFile['tmp_name']));
```

if u just want to test

> 'source' => '@'.$imgLocalPath;